# Loop on Ansible items

Tags: loops, ansible

I have the following data as input:

```yaml
list_domains:
  domain1:
    server_name: "domain1.com"
    server_alias:
      - "domain1.fr"
    certificate:
      method: "webroot"
    php_custom_values:
      memory_limit: "128M"
    database:
      type: "mysql"
    cms:
      type: "prestashop"
  domain2:
    server_name: domain2.com
    php_custom_values:
      memory_limit: "512M"
```

To create many domains on many hosts.

I use this loop to create all domains configurations:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: "Create domain configuration"
    include_role:
      name: webserver/domain
    loop: "{{ list_domains| dict2items }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: domain
```

But I'd like to update only one domain configuration when the playbook is run with a domain name as extra variable

For example:

```sh
ansible-playbook domains.yml -e target=domain1
```

But I didn't manage to extract one item in the dict and use it in the role.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell to put you on track

```yaml
---
- name: Not fully tested example only playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    # Your original data
    list_domains: <your full dict as in example>

    # The loopable list of domains
    my_list: "{{ list_domains| dict2items }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Filter out the list if target is defined
      set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_list | selectattr('key', '==', target) }}"
      when: target is defined

    - name: Do the job with the list
      include_role:
        name: webserver/domain
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: domain
```

Comment: selectattr was the function I was looking for. Thanks for the clue

Answer (score 0):

Adding `| list`  makes the job

Here is the complete filter :

```
    - name: Filter out the list if target is defined
  set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list | selectattr('key', '==', target) | list }}"
  when: target is defined
```

Comment: If you are using ansible < 2.10, the `list` filter is mandory. You can omit it in ansible >=2.10.